# Do I need two about's in the following sentence or only one?

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions

> "It's more like *not forgetting* (about) death than *thinking* about it.

Do I need the "about"? Why or why not?

Not "forgetting death" turns up more Google [results](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1280&bih=891&tbm=bks&q=%22not%20forgetting%20%20death%22&oq=%22not%20forgetting%20%20death%22&gs_l=serp.3...1354.1354.0.1633.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.0.0.5fRdq0aO-fk). However, I've heard phrases like "don't forget about me" and adding "about" kinda adds symmetry to the sentence. But, I'm not very sure.

Comment: To forget (about) something also means to stop thinking about something. The sentence doesn't make sense as "not forgetting (about ) something =  thinking about it.  Why do you want to repeat the same sense?

Comment: I don't see any problem with *It's more like not forgetting about death than thinking about it.* Google result and Ngram gives more result for "thinking about death"

Comment: We attempt to eliminate the grammar tag. (Almost) Please don't tag your questions with it. See [*A proposed solution to the Grammar dilemma*](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/a-proposed-solution-to-the-grammar-dilemma-please-contribute-your-answers-t?cb=1)

Answer (score 1):

'Forget' meaning 'stop thinking about something or someone ' can be followed by the direct object or the preposition 'about'. Both examples are correct. See Dictionary.cambridge.org.